# Can not set java.util.Date field ru.sfedu.diplomabackend.model.User.created to ru.sfedu.diplomabackend.model.User

Tags: java

I want to save user in database, but i have an error about saving date:

```
Error accessing field [private java.util.Date ru.sfedu.diplomabackend.model.User.created] by reflection for persistent property [ru.sfedu.diplomabackend.model.User#created] : User(id=null, email=user@gmail.com, password=$2a$12$H3Wm1XGRPFse5AP0ZnzAs.SPiGMBp35mRgqI5WLwu1Zp/1RVRSnwC, firstName=Da, lastName=Mi, created=Fri Jun 04 21:51:39 MSK 2021, goalSet=[], diaryDays=[])
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Date field ru.sfedu.diplomabackend.model.User.created to ru.sfedu.diplomabackend.model.User
```

User class:

```
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date created;
```

UserPostRequestDto class:

public class UserPostRequestDto {

```
private String email;
private String password;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Date created;
public UserPostRequestDto(User user) {
    email = user.getEmail();
    password = user.getPassword();
    firstName = user.getFirstName();
    lastName = user.getLastName();
}
public User toUser() {
    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setPassword(password);
    user.setFirstName(firstName);
    user.setLastName(lastName);
    user.setCreated(new Date());
    return user;
}
```

rest controller:

```
 public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestBody UserPostRequestDto userPostRequestDto) {
    var user = userPostRequestDto.toUser();
    //user.setCreated(new Date());
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    return userDao.addUser(user)
            ? ResponseEntity.ok(user)
            : new ResponseEntity<>("Invalid user", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: Note: Use `Instant` in modern code instead of `Date`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I'm not sure that it is the reason of the error :(

Comment: It's not; that's why I marked it as a note. It will make your life easier, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your error clearly says that you are trying to assign a `ru.sfedu.diplomabackend.model.User` object into the `ru.sfedu.diplomabackend.model.User.created` field that holds a `java.util.Date` object. Square peg, round hole.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Date field ru.sfedu.diplomabackend.model.User.created to ru.sfedu.diplomabackend.model.User

You must have some offending code not shown to us here.

P.S. As commented, you should never use the terrible `Date` class. Replaced years ago by `java.time.Instant`.